# Sort description term in alphabetical order moving following DOM element with it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to sort the following by the value thats inside the link of the `<dt>` while moving with the sort the following `<dd>` DOM element with it.

Sample:

```
<div class="courseTree">
  <dt><input class="dept_checkbox" type="checkbox"><a href="">BBBB</a></dt>
  <dd class="options">
    <li>COURSE_BBB-AAA</li>
    <li>COURSE_BBB-CCC</li>
  </dd>     

  <dt><input class="dept_checkbox" type="checkbox"><a href="">AAAA</a></dt>
  <dd class="options">
    <li>COURSE_AAA-AAA</li>
    <li>COURSE_AAA-CCC</li>
  </dd>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
<div class="courseTree">
  <dt><input class="dept_checkbox" type="checkbox"><a href="">AAAA</a></dt>
  <dd class="options">
    <li>COURSE_AAA-AAA</li>
    <li>COURSE_AAA-CCC</li>
  </dd>

  <dt><input class="dept_checkbox" type="checkbox"><a href="">BBBB</a></dt>
  <dd class="options">
    <li>COURSE_BBB-AAA</li>
    <li>COURSE_BBB-CCC</li>
  </dd>     
</div>
```

I tried the following but no luck.

```
var dl = $(".courseTree");
$(dl).children('dt').each(function() {
    $(this).append($(this).next());
});
var sortedItems = $(dl).children('dt').sort();
$.each(sortedItems, function(i, dt) {
    $(dl).append(dt);
    $(dt).children('dd').each(function(j, dd) {
        $(dl).append($(dd));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add them into an array and then sort it.

```js
arr = [];
$(".container").each(function () {
  arr.push($(this).detach());
});
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
  return a.find("a:first").html() > b.find("a:first").html()
});
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  $(".courseTree").append(arr[i][0].outerHTML);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="courseTree">
  <div class="container">
  <dt><input class="dept_checkbox" type="checkbox"><a href="">BBBB</a></dt>
  <dd class="options">
    <li>COURSE_BBB-AAA</li>
    <li>COURSE_BBB-CCC</li>
  </dd>     
  </div>

 <div class="container">
  <dt><input class="dept_checkbox" type="checkbox"><a href="">AAAA</a></dt>
  <dd class="options">
    <li>COURSE_AAA-AAA</li>
    <li>COURSE_AAA-CCC</li>
  </dd>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer depends on there being a `div.container` which would break other elements in the app. You could probably use the containers to re-organize then pull them out once its finished?

Comment: You can also just change the name of the class

Comment: Yes, you can. but it does not represent output mentioned in the question I'm trying to do. Adding it into new divs breaks other areas of the application for me.

Comment: Adding  `$(".container").contents().unwrap();` at the end with your code did the job!